# How to create vm instance from machine image with the different boot disk size in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine

I want to create a virtual machine instance from a machine image. The machine image size has a boot disc of 20GB, but I want to create a VM with a boot disc of 30GB. I tried the command below, but it didn't work for me. Could someone please assist me with this?

```html
gcloud beta compute instances create test-vm --project=test-2511 --zone us-east1-b --network=demo-vpc --subnet=demo-subnet --machine-type=n2-standard-2 --boot-disk-size=30GB --source-machine-image projects/test-2511/global/machineImages/demo --service-account 1266-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: What error you got?

Comment: I haven't  got any error. VM instance got created but the boot disc size is still showing as 20 GB